# System of linear equations and condition number

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

The relative error of the solution of a system of linear equation $Ax=b$, for any [natural norm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NaturalNorm.html) $\|\cdot\|$ is bounded by
$$
\frac{1}{\| A\| \|A^{-1} \|} \frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|} \le \frac{\|e\|}{\|x\|} \le 
\| A\| \|A^{-1} \| \frac{\|r\|}{\|b\|}
$$
where $r=Ax_{approx}-b$ and $e=x_{approx}-x_{exact}$. We call $\| A\| \|A^{-1} \|$ condition number of the square matrix $A$ and is denoted by $Cond(A)$. The condition number is greater than or equal to one. I read that the condition number heavily depends on the norm used. But since $Cond(A) \ge 1$ we can say when the condition number is small, $\|r\| / \|b\|$ is a good measure for the error.

I'm confused about this. Since the condition number depends on the norm used, then if a norm minimize the condition number i.e. $Cond(A)\approx 1$ and thus minimize the error, another norm can maximize that. Then when the condition number is small how we can say $\|r\| / \|b\|$ is a good measure for the error?

Comment: There is nothing magical here.It is just a bound, so for specific matrix you can choose a norm generating the condition number which is nearest to 1. The inequality still holds true for any norm. Just be careful that for different norms of matrix the vector norm may or may not coincide. So the ratio $||e||/||x||$ may or may not be different. It is better to compare norms that are the same for vectors.

Comment: Well, the bound is generally true for *any* vector norm but the matrix norm defining the condition number is restricted to the operator norm defined by the vector norm. One cannot choose just any vector and matrix norms here.

Comment: Where can I find a proof of this result?

Answer (score 0):

Good question.

Note that the condition number of a matrix $A$ depends on the norm used. This is true. However, if a matrix $A$ is well-conditioned, it will stay well-conditioned with respect to other values also. On the other hand, if a matrix $A$ is ill-conditioned (having a high value of $\kappa(A)$) with respect to some norm, then it will be ill-conditioned with respect to other norms also. In a finite-dimensional Banach space, all norms are equivalent, and the choice of a norm does not affect the sensitivity analysis of solutions of linear systems $A \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{B}$.